# Inverting arithmetic functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

I know that if $$F(n)=\sum_{d|n}f(d)$$ then $$f(p^e)=F(p^e)-F(p^{e-1})$$
Let $F(n)=\sum_{d|n}f(d)$ and assume $F(n)$ is multiplicative, so $F(1)=1$. Find the formula for $f(n)$ when $F(n)=1$ for all $n$. Because $F(n)=1$ for all $n$, we can write $n=p^e$ By plugging $F(p^e)=1$ into the formula, I get $$f(p^e)=1-1=0$$ but this doesn't seem correct. Do I need to set $F(1)=f(1)=1$ and then let every other term $f(n)=0$ to satisfy the sum?

Comment: The formula $f(p^e) = F(p^e) - F(p^{e-1})$ only makes sense for $e \geqslant 1$. For $n = 1$ you directly get $f(1) = F(1)$ from the definition of $F$.

Comment: Right. Well then how would i show that $f(n)=0$ for $n>1$? I'm a little thrown off by the general n on this one

Comment: Depends on what you already know. Do you know that the multiplicativity of $F$ implies that of $f$?

Comment: Yes. So something like $f(p^2)=0=f(p)f(p)$ to show that each $f(p)=0$?

Comment: No, for $f(p^2) = f(p)f(p)$ you'd need _complete_ multiplicativity. For prime powers, $f(p^e) = F(p^e) - F(p^{e-1})$ gives you $f(p^e) = 0$. For $n$ with two or more distinct prime factors you can use multiplicativity to get $f(n) = 0$.

Comment: Ah I forget about the coprime requirement. I think I have it now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76053/discussion-between-jakeryan34-and-daniel-fischer).